# Sort Select box by price with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectbox

I want the options to be sorted by price. I tried different codes but I was not successful!

This is my normal box:

```
 <select id="product-list">
 <option>product 1- [2$]</option>
  <option>product 2- [4$]</option>
    <option>product 3- [0.5$]</option>
    <option>product 4- [1.5$]</option>
    </select>
```

But I mean something like this:

```
 <select id="product-list">
 <option>product 3- [0.5$]</option>
  <option>product 4- [1.5$]</option>
    <option>product 1- [2$]</option>
    <option>product 2- [4$]</option>
    </select>
```

How can this be done with jQuery?

Comment: OK... so what have you tried? How are you creating the select element?

Comment: Information provided by you is insufficient for understanding what actually you want. Please provide more information as how data is being filled so you can create you option from there after sort or if its an array you can sort the array first and then pass it to select.

Comment: @Sanjeev_gupta2812 It is completely clear. Also the solution is not trivial so understandable why OP could not solve it or come up with some effort

Comment: Only a subtle difference from provided answer, but I suggest adding the price as either the `value=` property or `data-price=` and use a whole number unit for simplicity eg `data-price=200` `data-price=150` (rather than 2 and 1.5) then you don't need a complex (and potentially brittle) regex to extract it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not trivial

```js
const re = /\[(\d+\.?\d*)\$\]/; // matches an amount
const opts = $("#product-list").find("option"); // get the options
opts.sort(function(a,b) {  // sort them using the textContent 
  const a_amt = a.textContent.match(re)[1];
  const b_amt = b.textContent.match(re)[1];
  return a_amt-b_amt;
})
$("#product-list").html(opts); // re-insert the sorted options
$("#product-list")[0].selectedIndex = 0; // select the new first option
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="product-list">
  <option>product 1- [2$]</option>
  <option>product 2- [4$]</option>
  <option>product 3- [0.5$]</option>
  <option>product 4- [1.5$]</option>
</select>
```